# BottomSheet opening with only till half of the screen

Tags: flutter

BottomSheet doesn't not open with full screen width in Samsung Fold device.
I attach image for full info
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhKIL.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGWnK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT9m3.jpg)

I want to open with full screen width for any devices. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaQuery` to get the device width height.

```
void _showCustomBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8, // Adjust the width as needed
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Option 1'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Option 2'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            // Add more list tiles or widgets here
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

set the `isScrollControlled` property to `true` under `showModalBottomSheet` to get full height.

Comment: I already try this but not helped

Comment: Could you share your code? I can try to solve

Comment: i fix this now. Use showBottomsheet instead of showModalBottomsheet. And it is work

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the `Scaffold` widget's `showBottomSheet` method to display a BottomSheet. By default, this BottomSheet will take up the full width of the screen.

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: double.infinity, // Full screen width
        height: 300, 
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('BottomSheet Content'),
            // Add more widgets as needed
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```